# Issues with reverse Linked List using recursion

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to reverse a linked list using recursion. Everything goes well until the end and I end up getting broken result.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```js
const reverseLinkedList = (node, newChildOldParent=null ) => {
    if( node.next ){
        reverseLinkedList(node.next, node);
    }
    node.next = newChildOldParent;
    return node;
}

const someList = {
    value: 1,
    next: {
        value: 2,
        next: {
            value: 3,
            next: {
                value: 4,
                next: null
            }
        }
    }
};

console.log(reverseLinkedList( someList ))
```

I get

```
{ value: 1, next: null }
```

Instead of the reversed linked List.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: and `debugger;` too @FrankerZ :)

Comment: `console.log()` is forever

Comment: your problem is that you are reversing the list alright, but you are getting the first element again in the end (as the stack unfolds). Your first element is now the last and doesn't have a `next` node.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Sandro. Appreciate your time.

Comment: @technoCorner you're welcome :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reversal is working fine, but you've lost track of the new head and instead return the old head which is now pointing to `null`. Here's a diagram of the stack calls:

```
curr: 1 next: 2
  curr: 2 next: 3
    curr 3: next: 4
      curr: 4 next: null
      curr: 4 next: 3
    curr: 3 next: 2
  curr: 2 next: 1
curr: 1 next: null <-- uh oh
```

You need to keep track of the new head, which is node 4. Here's another approach that passes the last node back to the head:

```js
const reverseLinkedList = (curr, prev) => {
    if (curr.next) {
        const newHead = reverseLinkedList(curr.next, curr);
        curr.next = prev;
        return newHead; // pass the new head up the list
    }
    
    curr.next = prev;
    return curr; // base case; return the tail
};

const someList = {
    value: 1,
    next: {
        value: 2,
        next: {
            value: 3,
            next: {
                value: 4,
                next: null
            }
        }
    }
};

console.log(reverseLinkedList(someList));
```

Comment: Calling it `newHead` instead of `next` might be more appropriate

Comment: "the (list of) next nodes", yeah why not. But it is not the next node, so it's confusing.

Comment: I see what you're saying here and agree with you--I'll update to clarify.