# Better way to reverse a linkedlist in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, linked-list

I tried this:

```
const reverseLinkedList = (head) => {
  if (!head) {
    return {
      HEAD: null,
      curr: null,
    };
  }

  // Checking if current node is the last node or not
  if (!head.next) {
    let node = new Node(head.value);
    return {
      HEAD: node,
      curr: node,
    };
  }

  let { curr, HEAD } = reverseLinkedList(head.next);

  curr.next = new Node(head.value);

  return {
    HEAD,
    curr: curr.next,
  };
};

let { HEAD } = reverseLinkedList(list.head);
console.log(HEAD);
```

And my Node class:

```
class Node {
  constructor(val) {
    this.value = val;
    this.next = null;
  }
}
```

here `head` is the main LinkedList's head, and `HEAD` is the head of new one. I'm using `stack` here. And the algorithm is in `linear` complexity.

Instead of creating **new Node** everytime, I think there is some better way to implement this.
Can you suggest some other ways?
Also is it possible to use `queue` here to achieve this?

Comment: Best not to use recursion, but if you have to there's [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51641450/6243352). Queues and stacks seem irrelevant to linked list algorithms, since LLs are lower-level data structures, usually used to implement such higher-level data structures.

Comment: _Also is it possible to use queue here to achieve this_ Queue is First in first out, so doesn't seem relevant unless you are ok with algorithmic tweaks in there. However, there do exist iterative solution for this.

Comment: yeah got your point

Comment: yep, iterative one also worked well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to reverse the list iteratively, we

- Capture current node's next node in some other temp variable.
- Make current node's next point to previous node.
- Store current Node as the previous one.
- Move to next node with the help of temp node captured in 1<sup>st</sup> step.
- Repeat from step 1 again.

**Snippet:**

```
const reverseLinkedList = (head) => {
  let temp = head, prev = null;

  while(temp != null){
    let nextNode = temp.next;
    temp.next = prev;
    prev = temp;
    temp = nextNode;
  }

   return prev; // as this is the new head
};
```